# How to get rid of flurry errors after upgrade?

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have had an adroid application that compiled in release version (signed application version) just fine. I have upgraded to flurry analytics 6.1.0 and now I get a whole lot of errors while making a release APK.

The errors are:

```
3:05:56 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz$a
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz$a
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz$a
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$1$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$2: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$2: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz$a
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$2: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz$a
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$2: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz$a
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$2: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz$a
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.Post$2: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.dz$a
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.ej
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.ff
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.gz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.ej
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.ej
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.ej
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.ej
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.ff
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.gz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.gz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.android.tumblr.TumblrShare: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.gz
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: com.flurry.sdk.lw: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.i
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] Warning: there were 35 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-10-09 13:05:56 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

It is very annoying that a new version of library breaks the application. At least, they should give some warning about that.

What are this errors? Why do they appear and most important, how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

"com.flurry.sdk.dz" belongs to FlurryAds-X.X.X.jar lib.
if you not use ad, try below, it work:

```
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
```